# ¿Por qué me da este error? Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

El error que me da es el siguiente:

Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro\Pagina.php:678
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro\Pagina.php(678): mysqli_fetch_array(false)
#1 {main}
thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro\Pagina.php** on line **678**

No se a que se debe, hasta hace poco no daba ningún error y funcionaba pero ahora no y creo que no he cambiado nada. Lo único que se es que afecta a una consulta mysql y el código es el siguiente:

```
<?php $sql="SELECT*FROM preguntas WHERE grupo = '".$grupopregun1."' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $pregunta = $mostrar['preguntas'];
    ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php $sql="SELECT*FROM preguntas WHERE preguntas = '".$pregunta."' ORDER BY RAND()";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $id = $mostrar['id'];
    ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Cualquier ayuda/consejo se agradece porque estoy desesperado. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Esa sintaxis en la consulta es sospechosa: ¿probaste reemplazando `SELECT*FROM` por `SELECT * FROM`?

Comment: @padaleina Lo he cambiado en todo el documento y sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Como te han indicado, fijate en el log de PHP, y además en el contenido tanto de la variable `$conn` como la de `$sql`. ¿Es correcto el contenido de ambas? ¿Está bien definido el host, usuario, contraseña y bbdd en la cadena de conexión? (si vas a [edit] tu pregunta con esa info, _recuerda enmascarar las contraseñas_).

Comment: @padaleiana La variable conn no tiene ningún error, ya que otros SELECT sí funcionan. Lo que más me desconcierta es que funcione unas veces y otras de el error. Si diera error siempre seria lógico, pero como no es extraño.

Answer (score 3):

El error se produce porque la operación mysqli_query no se ha realizado correctamente. Puedes hacer varias cosas para averiguar que ocurre:
Probar la operación (el select) directamente
Mirar el archivo log de errores de PHP
Puedes colocar una sentencia de aviso

```
if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Esto te dará el mensaje de error asociado a la operación que se acaba de realizar.
No olvides que los errores siempre pueden ocurrir y es necesario alguna forma de aviso o control.

Comment: Muchas gracias lo voy a probar a ver si se arregla.

Comment: No sé porqué pero no me imprime nada. Como si no hubiera ningún error. Solo muestra el anteriormente dicho.

Comment: Pon un exit($sql) justo despues del $return =mysqli_query (que es donde se produce el error, supongo que la linea 678). Te imprimirá la cadena SELECT, pues prueba esa cadena directamente en la base de datos (tendras phpMyAdmin, o con el workshop que tengas o con el cliente mysql)) . Ahi debiera darte algún mensaje del error más concreto.

Comment: No me da ningún error cuando la introduzco en mysql.

Comment: Si la cadena de consulta es correcta solo queda la variable  $conn, no se me ocurre otra. De todas formas mira el archivo log de PHP

Comment: La variable conn no tiene ningún error, ya que otros SELECT sí funcionan. Lo que más me desconcierta es que funcione unas veces y otras de el error. Si diera error siempre seria lógico, pero como no es extraño.

Comment: Errores intermitentes, puffff. Supongo que a ese código (el query del error) siempre llegas por el mismo camino, y por tanto con la variable bien inicializada. Si es así el código debe estar bien. ¿problema de conexión o en el servidor de la BD?. Crea un log que recoja los valores de $conn y $sql, cuando se produzca el error podrás ver sus valores para comparar.